# MySQL - INSERT command with conditions

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a table called eleva with the columns inicio_periodo, id, and i want to populate another table with some data from this one,
when a condition is satisfied. I'm trying the where statement that should work, but it inserts on the other table regardless of the condition, here's my code:

```
for($i=0; $i < $tamanho_array_eleva-1; $i++) {
    if($array_eleva[$i+1] - $array_eleva[$i] > 1){
        $con->query("
                    INSERT INTO eventos_dias
                    SELECT DATE(inicio_periodo),'1','0','0','0'
                    FROM eleva
                    WHERE id = $array_eleva[$i] AND 0<=HOUR(inicio_periodo)<6");
        $con->query("
                    INSERT INTO eventos_dias
                    SELECT DATE(inicio_periodo),'0','1','0','0'
                    FROM eleva
                    WHERE id = $array_eleva[$i] AND 6<=HOUR(inicio_periodo)<12");
        $con->query("
                    INSERT INTO eventos_dias
                    SELECT DATE(inicio_periodo),'0','0','1','0'
                    FROM eleva
                    WHERE id = $array_eleva[$i] AND 12<=HOUR(inicio_periodo)<18");
        $con->query("
                    INSERT INTO eventos_dias
                    SELECT DATE(inicio_periodo),'0','0','0','1'
                    FROM eleva
                    WHERE id = $array_eleva[$i] AND 18<=HOUR(inicio_periodo)<24");
    }
}
```

I know it isn't working because currently on the table i just have data with the hour 16... but it's executing all the inserts regardless. Does anyone see an error?

Just if helps: my idea is to populate the other table with the selected values if the condition `number<=hour(inicio_periodo)<number` is satisfied. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not print out the error (if it exists) after each query?

Comment: It is running, but in the wrong way. i mean the error "why it is inserting regardless the where condition". But thanks anyway.

Comment: It is bond to insert a new row if the select part finds something to insert

Comment: But when i state SELECT ... WHERE <conditions>, doesn't it just insert with those conditions ?

Comment: The insert say lets try doing an insert from this data. The select does the selection of the data. i.e. find this data from those tables **WHERE** that condition is true

Comment: So, i don't get it why it isn't working the right way, cause, on my current table, i just have the hour 16, and only 16. So, in my opinion, the inserts out of 12 to 18h shouldn't work. Don't them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis query shows you why:

```
mysql> SELECT 1<= 16 < 6;
+------------+
| 1<= 16 < 6 |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
```

As it's

```
mysql> SELECT (1 <= 16) < 6;
+---------------+
| (1 <= 16) < 6 |
+---------------+
|             1 |
+---------------+
```

Which becomes:

```
mysql> SELECT 1 < 6;
+-------+
| 1 < 6 |
+-------+
|     1 |
+-------+
```

Likewise: `18 <= 16 < 24` => `(18 <= 16) < 24` => `0 < 24` => `1`

In short, use `value BETWEEN min AND max`, that's what it's for, or use separate checks:

```
mysql> SELECT 16 BETWEEN 1 AND 6;
+--------------------+
| 16 BETWEEN 1 AND 6 |
+--------------------+
|                  0 |
+--------------------+

 mysql> SELECT 1 <= 16 AND 16 < 6;
+--------------------+
| 1 <= 16 AND 16 < 6 |
+--------------------+
|                  0 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: And that's it! :) But kinda "dumb" in my opinion. Thanks a lot! Including the explanation.